# tintColor props is not working for ios react native , but its working for android

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native

I am trying to change the color of an image in my project . I am using tintColor to change the color , but its working in android but its not working in ios .

```
what would be correct solution or this . Please suggest.



 Version - "react-native": "0.70.6",

    import {ImageBackground} react-native
    <ImageBackground
                  source={require('../../../images/group-53817.png')}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  style={[styles.headerLeft]}
                  tintColor={theme?.headerRingImageColor}
                />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with tintColor not working on iOS in React Native. Unfortunately, tintColor is not supported on iOS for ImageBackground.However, there is alternative approaches you can take to achieve the desired effect.

```
const YourComponent = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.headerLeft]}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('../../../images/group-53817.png')}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: theme?.headerRingImageColor,
            opacity: 0.5, // Adjust the opacity to control the intensity of the color overlay
          }}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
```

if still not work then you can try react-native-svg like below

```
const TintedImage = ({ source, tintColor, style }) => {
  return (
    <Svg style={style}>
      <Image
        href={source}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
        fill={tintColor}
      />
    </Svg>
  );
};

const YourComponent = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={[styles.headerLeft]}
    >
      <TintedImage
        source={require('../../../images/group-53817.png')}
        tintColor={theme?.headerRingImageColor}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```